# Angular universal-starter -- prerender component multiple times with different data

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, prerender, angular-universal

I am trying to use the **prerender.ts** from the offical universal-starter project to render a component for all the route parameters. I have a **working** angular application which works like a newspaper with a frontpage containing links to many articles. The article is displayed in its own component and depending on the route-parameters I get the data.

```
{
    path: 'artikel/:id',
    component: ArticleComponent,
    data: {title: environment.pageName + ' - Artikel'},
    resolve: {article: ArticleResolveService},
},
```

Now to make my app SEO friendly I am using the [Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) from angular to prerender my components to static html files. My basic components get prerenderd fine but **I try to render the article component multiple times for each article**. Currently my prerender.ts looks like this:

```
// Load zone.js for the server.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync, existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ROUTES } from './static.paths';

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const BROWSER_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'browser');

// Load the index.html file containing referances to your application bundle.
const index = readFileSync(join('browser', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

let previousRender = Promise.resolve();

// Iterate each route path
ROUTES.forEach(route => {
  var fullPath = join(BROWSER_FOLDER, route);

  // Make sure the directory structure is there
  if(!existsSync(fullPath)){
    mkdirSync(fullPath);
  }
  // Writes rendered HTML to index.html, replacing the file if it already exists.
  previousRender = previousRender.then(_ => renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    document: index,
    url: route,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  })).then(html => writeFileSync(join(fullPath, 'index.html'), html));
});
```

The ROUTES are defined like so:

```
export const ROUTES = [
    '/home',
    '/suche',
    '/artikel'
];
```

This generates the following output. I have marked what I would like to end up with eventually:

```
/dist
|
+-- home
  |
  +--index.html
+-- suche
  |
  +--index.html
+-- article(as it is right now)
    |
    +-- index.html
+-- article(as it should be)
    |
    +-- 90(id from article - see routing)
        |
        +--index.html
    +-- 91
        |
        +--index.html
    +-- 92
        |
        +--index.html
```

Each index.html should containt the prerenderd **article.component with the corresponding data**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to share the code you've written so far which attempts to solve your problem, so that we can help you get it working. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service but rather a problem-solving one. Regarding the architecture of your app, it sounds like you need a service which gets the items from the API/backend, which is then injected into the component and the component calls the method, e.g `getItem(id: number)` to get the data.

Comment: Hi Tom, I have edited my question now to be a bit more precise. What you have described is already working in my app. What is missing is just the SEO part for which I have to prerender each article to static html

Comment: my one is also similar to this. Pre-rendering all the routes that take parameters.

Comment: Where do the article id's come from? A third party api maybe? If so you need to fetch which id's it needs to render from that third party api (or hard code them?) Then add a another loop like ROUTES.forEach to run that code for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one resolution:

replacing request url before rendering

req.url='/artikel/1';

```
... 

if(req.url.match(/*...isArtikel...*/)) {
  req.url='/artikel/1'; // Or another id. One id for every
}
res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] }, (err: any, render: any) => {
    /*...Cache...*/
    res.send(render);
});
...
```